# Energy regenerative snubber for flyback converter

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, electromagnetism, flyback

I am trying out the regenerative snubber design in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/215381319.pdf page 13. The circuit configuration is shown in the figure below:
[image]

I am unable to derive the following parameters after selection of Cclamp and Nt

1. I am trying to understand the peak current of the primary side mosfet so that I can set a maximum current limit in the controller I will be using. Kindly explain to me how I can derive this peak current.
2. Also explain to me how I can derive the peak, average and rms currents flowing through Dreg, D1 and the output diode (D0) for power loss calculation.

Thanks